# Format date in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I format date like `"Tue 01/19/2016"` to show as `"Tuesday, January 19"

I tried

```
$scope.date = "Tue 01/19/2016";
<p>{{date | date:'EEEE/MMMM/d'}}</p>
```

output

```
"Tue 01/19/2016"
```

Is there a way to format it to show as Tuesday, January 19

**Update: Got it working.**

```
var date = new Date("Tue 01/19/2016")
{{date | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d'}}
```

Thanks

Comment: All the format types can be found on Angular's docs for [Date Filter API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Make it easy for yourself include moment.js for angular: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make a date object.

```
$scope.date =  new Date("Tue 01/19/2016");
```

Than you can use the date filter

```
{{date | date:'EEEE/MMMM/d'}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also got it working. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The date variable cannot be a string like this. The [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) says:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ).

So, one option is to define the `$scope.date` variable as a Date object like this:

```
$scope.date = new Date('2016-01-19');
```

Also, your filter string needs to be changed to output your desired result:

```
<p>{{ date | date:'EEEE, MMMM d' }}</p>
```

But, as you see, the date string is not the same as you have, so if you are receiving it string from an external source in your app (e.g. from an API), you'll have to manually convert it to a compatible string format, which can be directly the AngularJS compatible string format (as in the docs), or one of the [Date object compatible string options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method may also help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

{{date | date:'EEEE, MMMM, dd'}}